# Uploading a file to a url in a Play Framework Functional Test

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

So I have a method in one of my controllers that expects a CSV file that it will then process. This all seems to be working fine but I'd like to add some tests just to verify it. However, I'm not 100% sure how to go about testing it.

I wrote a quick test method that should work (as far as I can see) but I get the following error:

```
A java.lang.RuntimeException has been caught, java.io.FileNotFoundException: File is not a normal file.
```

My code is as follows:

Controller method:

```
/* client-side scripts dictate the incoming
 * file will be called "files".
 */
public static void upload(File files) {
    //do some work
}
```

Controller Test method:

```
/* this test class and the file "valid-data.csv"
 * are in the same folder.
 */
@Test
public void upload() {
    File csvFile = Fixtures.loadYaml("valid-data.csv", File.class);
    Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
    fileMap.put("files", csvFile);

    Response response = POST("/api/upload", new HashMap<String, String>(), fileMap);
    assertIsOk(response);
}
```

Am I going about this the right way? I'm using Play Framework 1.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this.
Turns out it was a simple file location problem. As I mentioned, the test class and the csv file are in the same folder, called 'test'. However, when loading the file, I still need to specify that its in the 'test' folder.

Just had to change the first line of the test function from:

```
File csvFile = Fixtures.loadYaml("valid-data.csv", File.class);
```

to:

```
File csvFile = new File("test/valid-data.csv");
```

And it works fine now.